# What kind of plant is this, I never seen this plant before

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents

A friend of mines has given me a plant. However, it came without any instructions and no name. Does anyone know what type of plant this is and how to maintain it?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having trouble deciding whether this is Aeonium or Echeveria - Echeveria has quite thick leaves, Aeonium has somewhat thinner ones, but fortunately, both are classed as succulents and both have the same requirements for care. I'm inclined to go for Aeonium, but time will tell... links here to image of Aeonium http://www.naturfoto.cz/eonium-lanzarotske-fotografie-10092.html and for Echeveria (scroll down to E. dondo as an example) http://www.thesucculentgarden.com.au/echev.html

In terms of care, a windowsill that receives some sunlight is perfect, though some shade in the height of summer on a southfacing windowsill will be necessary, particularly in the middle of the day. Some fresh air is useful too, so an open window nearby to provide good airflow is a good idea. Average warmth from spring to autumn - succulents like a marked difference between night and day temperatures, unlike most houseplants. Keep cool in winter, 50-55degF is ideal. Watering differs between winter and spring to autumn - water as any other houseplant from spring through to autumn, allowing the surface of the potting soil to become slightly dry to the touch, then water thoroughly, emptying out any outer pot or tray after 30 minutes. In winter, water infrequently, around once every 1-2 months.

In regard to watering, that's going to be a bit difficult - the plant has filled the pot from side to side, so it's impossible to touch the potting soil and impossible to water the soil without soaking the plant, so I suggest you repot into something wider, but not necessarily deeper.

Answer (score 1):

It can be too https://worldofsucculents.com/tacitus-bellus-chihuahua-flower/
If it blooms, you will be sure. Flowers differ in echeveria and aeonium.

Comment: Hi Joanna, you will be providing a better answer that is more useful to everyone if you add more than a link.  Tell us about the plant in your words including why you think it is this one.

Answer (score 0):

Tacius bellus, or actually Graptopetalum bellum, is a plant originating from Mexico. [image]
[image]

Graptopetalum is a small genus of the family Crassulaceae. They are perennial succulent plants and native to Mexico and Arizona. They all have thick leaves forming rosettes with star-shaped flowers from white to pink on long stems. All require lots of sun to look their best. They are similar looking to Echeverias, although they are generally considered closer to Sedums.

However, I must admit, after some thought, that I was probably wrong. I thought it was a bit lightless and young specimen. However, it is too light green, should be rather gray-dark green, the leaves too narrow, too loosely arranged. After a closer look, I noticed very small hairs, or cloves on the edges of the leaves, that could indicate rather aeonium. But really, these rosette succulents are really hard to recognize with certainty.